# Easily monitor the CPU % use of a process

Tags: monitoring, process

I'm have a small ISP and currently we are running an application of a customer that it's creating high CPU pikes. Basically we have chrome tab running and automate a process to stresstest a web application, so chrome processes are created basically every minute. Here comes the fun part

To monitor this I had to literally record the screen of the server with the Microsoft resource monitor, but this is not the best way to follow up this.

I tried perfmon but I just cant get it... Don't really know how to use it and I feel a bit overwhelmed by this.

Is there a simple application out there that I can say, hey, monitor every process under chrome.exe and let me know when and for how long the pikes are?

Thanks a lot for reading and assisting on this.

Kind regards.

Comment: So you are stress testing the client side javascript? It sounds like from the post you want to test the performance of the web service, so why do you want to monitor the resource usage of chrome instead of IIS or nginx?

Comment: Hi! I kind of automate the process to stresstest chrome tabs, I don't use IIS or Nginx to do this.